# Couldn't Copy the text in PDF file made by Photoshop CS 2017

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, adobe, copy-paste, deep-linking

I have made a PDF document using Adobe Photoshop CS 2017. I am unable to copy the texts or redirect to the browser by clicking the URL links. How to do that?

Comment: Can you share the PDF so we can look at it and determine if the PDF that you created actually contains text and links? Or whether the permissions are set to allow you to be able to copy the text?

Comment: Photoshop is an image program and likely the text is an image

Comment: @BrandonHaugen.Sorry for the delay. and kindly find the below link is my PDF file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5Ap7m33kveURzR6ZmxfQTBnQWM/view